# Create a column using based on conditions on other two columns in pandas

Tags: string, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I want to create a column in pandas based on the conditions on other two columns. I was trying this with a for loop with if else condition but getting error in checking for string values.

My dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Area:['USA','India','China','UK','France','Germany','USA','USA','India','Germany'],
         "Sales":[2,3,7,1,4,3,5,6,9,10]})
```

I want to create a column RATING based on the condition:

If country is in ASIA and Sales >2, then 1

If country is in NA and Sales >3, then 1

If country is in EUR and Sales >=4, then 1
else 0

I am using a function:

```
ASIA=['India','China']
NA= ['USA']   
EUR=['UK','France','Germany']     
def label_race(row):
 if row['Area'].isin(ASIA) & row['Sales'] >2  :
   return 1
 if row['Area'].isin(NA) & row['Sales'] >3  :
   return 1  
 if row['Area'].isin(EUR) & row['Sales'] >=4  :
   return 1
 return 0  

df['Rating']=df.apply(lambda row: label_race(row),axis=1)
```

which is throwing following error:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'isin'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong in the function or any other way easier way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vectorized solution with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m = [df['Area'].isin(ASIA) & (df['Sales'] > 2), 
     df['Area'].isin(NA) & (df['Sales'] > 3), 
     df['Area'].isin(EUR) & (df['Sales'] >= 4)]
df['Rating'] = np.select(m, [1,1,1], default=0)

print (df)
      Area  Sales  Rating
0      USA      2       0
1    India      3       1
2    China      7       1
3       UK      1       0
4   France      4       1
5  Germany      3       0
6      USA      5       1
7      USA      6       1
8    India      9       1
9  Germany     10       1
```

Your solution should be changed with `in` and `and` instead `isin` and `&`:

```
def label_race(row):
 if row['Area'] in (ASIA) and row['Sales'] >2  :
   return 1
 if row['Area'] in (NA) and row['Sales'] >3  :
   return 1  
 if row['Area'] in (EUR) and row['Sales'] >=4  :
   return 1
 return 0  

df['Rating']=df.apply(lambda row: label_race(row),axis=1) 
print (df)
      Area  Sales  Rating
0      USA      2       0
1    India      3       1
2    China      7       1
3       UK      1       0
4   France      4       1
5  Germany      3       0
6      USA      5       1
7      USA      6       1
8    India      9       1
9  Germany     10       1
```

---

Difference is in performance:

```
#[10000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [216]: %timeit df['Rating1']=df.apply(lambda row: label_race(row),axis=1)
275 ms ± 11.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [217]: %timeit df['Rating'] = np.select(m, [1,1,1], default=0)
215 µs ± 3.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I try check @Anton vBR idea from comment:

```
def label_race(row):
 if row['Area'] in (ASIA) and row['Sales'] >2  :
   return 1
 elif row['Area'] in (NA) and row['Sales'] >3  :
   return 1  
 elif row['Area'] in (EUR) and row['Sales'] >=4  :
   return 1
 else:
   return 0  

df['Rating1']=df.apply(lambda row: label_race(row),axis=1) 

In [223]: %timeit df['Rating1']=df.apply(lambda row: label_race(row),axis=1)
268 ms ± 2.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```